# Banno OATH Cannot GET /v0/oidc/auth

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Completely working Banno simple-plugin-example using one AWS Linux server with NodeJS copied to be transitioned to work under a Microsoft IIS server with NodeJS and URL Rewrites and all that entails basically worked out; but fails when it gets to actual process of OATH apparently as getting a "Cannot GET /v0/oidc/auth" response. Tried a number of ideas; but looking for some ideas to try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the behavior that you saw, which makes me wonder if you ran into a temporary blip.

Assuming that we're talking about the [latest version (commit c8775db2e3d9ecb4ce9ca708475d81d5936adf0e)](https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example/commits/main) of the `Simple Plugin Example`, then there are a few things to check and/or try.

1. It'll be good to check that the *environment* value in your `config.js` is correct. The `config-EXAMPLE.js` in the repo uses https://digital.garden-fi.com which matches up with the *Garden* demo financial institution. However, if you're not running this with a `Client ID` and `Client Secret` that's from *Garden* (i.e. this is with a *different* financial institution) then you'll have to change that `environment` value as appropriate for your financial institution.
2. It'll be good to double-check that the `Client ID` and `Client Secret` match up with your [External Application](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/getting-started/#external-applications) which is configured for your plugin.
3. If you're running the `Simple Plugin Example` locally, then you can try navigating to the http://localhost:8080/dynamic URL which is expected by the plugin when the code is run locally. This is a good way to figure out if the sample code itself is running as expected.
4. Assuming the above is fine, it'll be good to double-check the "URL Rewrites" which you mentioned...it's unclear what those URL rewrites are doing, but it's possible that you have some code which is interfering with what the sample code is expecting.

Comment: Since the first three are all fine... On the fourth, are there ANY examples for a Windows IIS implementation as mentioned above as the Linux Apache ProxyPass solution is working. And we have IIS with URL Rewrite / Application Request Routing. So 'static' is working and 'dynamic' gets called; but is the issue is with the URL OAuth back and forth .

Comment: We don't have examples for a Windows IIS implementation. Given that the example is working on AWS Linux as-is, it sounds like you'll have to contact Microsoft for support with their Windows IIS product to figure out what's going on with that product.